# Chef: Provision certificates and private keys

Tags: chef-infra

Is there any best-practice in order to provide a certificate with a cookbook: We need to configure an nginx instance, and we want to configure an https channel. In order to get it we need to provision the machine with an certificate and a private key.

I don't quite get how to deal with that safely, or if there's any best-practice to get it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are many options, none conclusive enough to call "best". If you're on AWS, look at the SSM parameter store or S3 w/ bucket policies, otherwise look at things like Hashicorp Vault, Keywhiz, ecfg, etc.

I've got a talk up covering the general space at https://coderanger.net/talks/secrets/. Feel free to ping me on Slack if you have specific questions.

Comment: I've read a bit more about this topis. It's most likely we're going to use Chef Vault. Nevertheless it stands for saving secrets, so, I need to store my certificates on there, but I also need to create a certificate file into my nodes. Is there any cookbook to accomplish this?

Comment: You would write that recipe yourself, but it's literally one file resource.